# How to re-scale bone keyframes and objects at the same time?

Tags: animation, rigging, dopesheet

I'm making an animation, where a character takes an object - it's working fine - but now I want to re-scale a part of the animation to make it faster (for example, I have 500 frames and need to scale down the frames 300 to 400); however, when I choose they keyframes, (not with the Dope-Sheet) Blender will only allow me to select either the animated bones, or object, that are keyframed. How can I select both so I don't have to re-do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Both *Dopesheet* and *Graph Editor* show keyframes of all ***selected*** objects, you can box select <kbd>B</kbd> the keyframes and scale them, <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> .

[image]